# Unity Camera Layers while Using Deferred Lightning as Rendering Path

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, camera

I have a problem with Unity Camera layers. I have 4 cameras in my scene. MainCamera for the 3d scene, GUICamera for HUD, FogOfWarCamera and a NPCGUICamera for showing icons on top of enemies. MainCamera is parent of other ones. Camera depths are from back to front: MainCamera, NPCGUICamera, FogOfWarCamera and GUICamera.

I also use Deferred Lightning as Rendering Path for MainCamera and FogOfWarCamera.

Obviously I want GUI elements to be on top of everything and NPCGUI elements to be between the 3d scene and fog of war. But with this setup NPCGUI elements are invisible. Others work fine.

I searched for a solution and found out that some people say that using deferred lightning messes up camera layers but I couldn't find a solution or a workaround. Anybody dealt with this before?